# Set the drop down-menu background height to absolute position sub menu height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a multi level navigation on the page. The navigation has three to four levels. I want a full width background in the drop down menu including all the sub menus. Currently, I have done with the one level, but when on click of the first level menu, the second level menu arises then the background is not taking the height dynamically and same in the case of the third level menu. As the sub menus are in absolute position, the height of the background is not increasing dynamically. Can anyone help? I have one reference website.
http://www.qsc.com/... but from here i am unable to get the code. I am preparing my own code.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
 /* 
        // Show hide popover
        $(".dropdown").click(function(){
            $(this).find(".dropdown-menu").slideToggle("fast");
   
        });*/
  $('.dropdown-menu').hide(); 
  
  $('.nav ul li > a').click(function() {
 $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul').slideUp(300);
 $(this).next('ul').stop(true, false, true).slideToggle(300);
 return false;
 
  });
 
 
});
```

```css
/* not very relevant styling */
h1         { font-size: 20px; padding-top: 20px; }
.container { position: relative; margin: 20px auto 0 auto; width: 75%; }
.header    { background: #eee; }
.nav       { background: #ccc; }


/* relevant styling */

body { overflow-x: hidden; } /* trick from css-tricks comments */

/* FIRST LEVEL */

.nav > ul > li { 
    display: inline-block; 
    position: relative; 
    padding: 3px 10px 3px 0;
    z-index: 100;
 list-style:none;
}

.nav > ul > li > ul{
 width:100px}

.nav > ul > li > a{
 color:#939598;
 text-decoration:none;
}

/* Level 1 Drop Down */
.dropdown-menu > li {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
  /* solve the 4 pixels spacing between list-items */
}
.dropdown-menu > li:first-child {
 margin-left: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
 position: relative;
 list-style:none;
}

/* SECOND LEVEL ( background -color) of full width bg*/
.nav > ul > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    padding: 0 1000em; /* trick from css-tricks comments */
    margin: 0 -1000em; /* trick from css-tricks comments */
    z-index: 101;   
    background:#f2f2f2;
}





/*second level menu*/
.nav li ul li ul li:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #7f7f7f;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}


.nav > ul > li > ul > li {
    padding: 3px 0;
 color:#939598;
 text-decoration:none;


}

.nav > ul > li > ul > li > a{color:#939598;
 text-decoration:none;}
 
 .dropdown-menu li a{
 color:#939598;
 text-decoration:none;  
}

 .dropdown-menu li ul li{
  color:#939598;
 text-decoration:none;
  padding-left:5px;}
 
 
 
.dropdown-menu  > li > ul {
 text-align: left;
 display: none;
 color:#939598;
 text-decoration:none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 5px;
 left: 100%; 
 z-index: 999999; /* if you have YouTube iframes, is good to have a bigger z-index so the video can appear above the video */
}


.nav .drop { 
 
    width:100%!important; /* or: width:1200px!important;*/
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

/*Third level menu*/

.dropdown-menu  > li > ul > li > ul {
 text-align: left;
display: none; 
 position: absolute;
 left: 100%;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 9999999;
 color:#939598;
 text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
    <!-- NAVIGATION -->    
    <div class="nav">
        <ul class="container">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="drop" href="#">Products</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Live Sound</a>
                    
                    <ul>
                    <li>Power AMplifiers</li>
                    <li>Loud Speakers</li>
                     <li>Power AMplifiers</li>
                    <li>Loud Speakers</li>
                     <li>Power AMplifiers</li>
                    <li>Loud Speakers</li>
                     <li>Power AMplifiers</li>
                    <li>Loud Speakers</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Touch Mix Mixers</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>GX Series</li>
                    <li>GXD Series</li>
                    <li>RMX Series</li>
                    <li>PLX2 Series</li>
                    <li>Powerlight three Series</li>
                    </ul>
                    
                    </li>
                    
                    </ul>
                    
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">System</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cinema</a></li>
                   
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="drop" href="#">Locations</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Location A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Location B</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Location C</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            
            
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="drop" href="#">Locations</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Location A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Location B</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Location C</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        
        </ul>
    </div>
    
</div>

<div class="content container">
    <p>All sorts of content</p>
    <p>All sorts of content</p>
    <p>All sorts of content</p>
    <p>All sorts of content</p>
    <p>All sorts of content</p>
    <p>All sorts of content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You need something like http://jsfiddle.net/w8sLxhr3/ ?

Comment: This is the code on which I am working. I want something like: http://www.qsc.com/. When you click on the product, it will open the sub menu and increase the height of the background dynamically.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You should give `background: #f2f2f2;` to `ul`.

Here i add menu class to ul and following css to menu class

```
.menu{
 background: #f2f2f2;
}
```

Check [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8sLxhr3/).

Hope it helps.

**Edit**

To do same like given link. You should make sub ul to `position:relative` when open. like following:

JQuery:

```
$(this).next('.sub').toggleClass('menu');
```

CSS:

```
.menu{
 background: #f2f2f2;
 position: relative !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="sub" >
```

You can toggle class `menu` which ul have class `sub` this way you can get you expected result.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8sLxhr3/1/)**

You can make changes as per your requirement.

Comment: yes, but the ul background is not coming to the full width.

Comment: Relative position is making the first level menu also coming down on click of the LI. I want all the li text should remain at the top. It shouldn't come down. I have tried this before, but I want all the sub menus should not affect the first level menus.

Comment: Thanks for helping! It will really help me to some extent. I will try to find out some solution.

Comment: @SonaliNanda to make first level menu as it is you need to change in HTML.